# how to add UIImageView overlay over a UITableViewController based controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

How does one in XCode XIB builder add a UIImageView to an existing MasterViewController that has a TableView and is based on NavigationController?

Scenario

- For example if you create a new project based on MasterDetail in XCode 4
- Then look at the MasterViewController.xib file - so want to add a UIImageView to this that could be used to overtake the screen up until a point after which the image view is made hidden to disappear.
- I'm trying to drag a UIImageView onto the page, and putting it just able TableView in the Objects column, however this doesn't work. Doesn't even show the image.
- So even just knowing how to drag-drop an image onto the MastViewController.xib such that it takes over the screen at startup would be a step forward (not sure if I need a view to encapsulate both the UIImageView and the TableView?)

Background

- Want to have an intermediate image that the iPhone app shows as it starts up
- Idea would be start up (static) image is show, then straight away go to MasterViewController which would show this same static image with an activity indicator on it
- Then when (is a background thread) the data preparation is down, the UIImageView could be made non-visible

PS. Some additional notes:

- Initially there is just a table view you see in MasterViewController.xib.
- If I drag an imageview in at the same level as the TableView it doesn't appear.
- If I create a new view in the XIB and put the tableview and uiimageview under this, I get an error when running "'-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "MasterViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so solved by:

- creating a top level "view" in the XIB
- put the UITableView & the new UIImageView under this new view
- but, had to change the interface line to inherit from UIViewController  NOT UITableViewController

Answer (score 0):

Is there a view or just a table view in your xib? If you want both a image view and a table view in the same view controller, you should have an ordinary `UIViewController` and let in implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols and add a table view and a image view to its view.

Comment: Initially there is just a table view you see in MasterViewController.xib.   If I drag an imageview in at the same level as the TableView it doesn't appear.  If I create a new view in the XIB and put the tableview and uiimageview under this, I get an error when running "'-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "MasterViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'"

Comment: That's why you need to inherit from UIViewController instead of UITableViewController and let your UIViewController implement the protocols i mentioned. Just make sure that your UIViewController still is the datasource and delegate of the table view.

Comment: yes thanks sanna - worked out in the end how this was part of the puzzle

Answer (score -1):

Just add Default.png in resource.

Comment: already have this - want a way to display it immediately after start up until model data has loaded